# SOAP request response giving undesired result

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I am trying to fetch response from SOAP request.Response is an xml data.When i try to convert data into String it shows <,> symbols as '&gt' and '&lt' with ';' at end.Then the xml parser is not able to parse it

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [NSString category for HTML.](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m)

It adds several functions to NSString which you may find useful, like:

```
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
```

You can run this function on your string and decode the HTML entities before giving the string to the XML parser.